# Vue.js transition-group reordering problem in Chrome

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, chromium

I have problem with difference vue `<transition-group>` behavior in Firefox and Chromium.

So, I have table with several columns (two in simplified example), inside each `<td>` lays `<transition-group>`, elements of those groups in the same table row are related. When number in first column had changed, values in second column should also get reordered.
All goes fine in Firefox:

[image: Firefox behavior]

But in Chromium it works correct only when number decreasing but when it increasing only second column gets animated:

[image: Chromium behavior]

So how to fix it?

```js
         let vm = new Vue({
            el: "#vue-block",
            data: {
               rows: [
                    {
                      label: 'row 1',
                      items: [
                        {number: 1, text: 'w'},
                        {number: 2, text: 'a'},
                        {number: 3, text: 's'},
                        {number: 4, text: 'd'}
                      ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            methods: {
                move: function(item, itemIdx) {
                  console.debug('item.Number', item.number);
                    let swapIdx = vm.rows[0].items.findIndex(function(inspectedItem, inspectedIdx) {
                    return inspectedItem.number === item.number
                        && itemIdx != inspectedIdx;
                });
                console.debug('swapIdx', swapIdx)
                if (swapIdx > -1) {
                    let swapItem = this.rows[0].items[swapIdx];
                    Vue.set(swapItem, 'number', itemIdx + 1);
                }

                    this.rows[0].items.sort((s1, s2) => {
                        return s1.number - s2.number;
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

```css
.item-list {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.item-list-enter-active,
.item-list-leave-active {
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.item-list-enter,
.item-list-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
.item-list-move {
  transition: transform 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="vue-block">
<table>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
        <td>
            {{ row.label }}<br>
          
            <transition-group name="item-list" tag="ul">
                <li v-for="(item, itemIdx) in row.items" v-bind:key="item.text">
                    <input type="number" v-model.number="item.number"
                           v-on:change="move(item, itemIdx)">          
                </li>      
            </transition-group>
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ row.label }}<br>
          
            <transition-group name="item-list" tag="ul">
                <li v-for="item in row.items" v-bind:key="item.text">
                    {{ item.text }}
                </li>      
            </transition-group>
        </td>      
    <tr>   
</table>
</div>
```

[Same demo](https://codepen.io/someone_else/pen/XxqejO?editors=1111) for easy forking.

Answer (score 0):

Your ending `<transition-group>` tag is not an ending tag. Simply change it to `</transition-group>`, and your code will work perfectly :)

*EDIT:* solved the problem by rewriting your code entierly: https://codepen.io/franzwilhelm/pen/YzGgoBz?editors=1111

Your issue was most probably related to Vue reactivity

Comment: Chromium 87.0.4280.141 still behave like on gif in my question

Comment: @Storm see edit in my answer :) Fixed your issue